# C++ cout or wcout a string contain "\n" isn't split the lines

Tags: string, c++11, winapi, cout, tdm-gcc

C++11 and compiler is TDM-GCC.

I made an ini file and read string from it(UCS-2 LE BOM), by WinAPI,
GetPrivateProfileStringW.

```
[String]
Example = Today\nYesterday\nApple
```

My function library will return a variable, std::wstring. And it looks fine.
Then use wcout, just like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
wstring readString = GetPrivateProfileStringW();    // Hide the details.
wcout << readString << endl;
```

And what do I get on my screen:

```
Today\nYesterday\nApple
```

What I want:

```
Today
Yesterday
Apple
```

I'm not sure why the "\n" is not work on this situation.

To avoid it, I can create multiple INI key and cout them using "endl".

But in this project, how many lines around here should be dynamic.

How do I cout the single string variable from Windows API on screen, become multiple lines?

Comment: `"\n"` is converted by the compiler, not `wcout`. Your INI file isn't passed through the compiler. The characters are written verbatim. This is the expected behavior. If you want line breaks, you're going to have to parse the string yourself.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you, I'll follow your suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence `\n` is only recognized by the *compiler* in source code as part of a literal string or character. It's nothing that is built into the library or any standard functions.

If you want the sequence to represent a newline inside input you have read from an external source, you have to handle it yourself.

Comment: Seems this is being more complex than I have imagined. Thank you. Perhaps find some code library is a good idea...

Comment: @2BEmperor It could just be as easy as replacing the string `"\\n"` with an actual newline `'\n'`

Comment: Not at all. I know that \\n from other programming language python etc. It's not me, Windows API added that \\.    I think I should add some special mark in INI, and replace them by \n in source code.

Comment: @2BEmperor Not double-backslash as a path separator, but because if you look for `"\n"` the compiler would replace it with a newline, which you wont find. You have to escape the backslash so the compiler actually searches for the actual backslash character directly followed by `'n'`. Try e.g. `std::cout << "hello\\nworld"` and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks! The \\n to \n convert function is done!